# jquery adding and removing form fileds dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am able to add fields but can't remove them. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

jQuery:

```
var FileInputsHolder    = $('#AddFileInputBox'); //Element where additional file inputs are appended
var MaxFileInputs       = 3; //Maximum number of file input boxs
// adding and removing file input box
var i = $("#AddFileInputBox div").size() + 1;

$("#AddMoreFileBox").click(function () {
    if (i < MaxFileInputs) {
        $('<h1>Patient-' + i + '</h1><div class="left-change" style="width:450px;"><div class="feild"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="FULL NAME" /><span id="val_name" class="val_error"></span> </div><div class="feild"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE" /><span id="val_phone" class="val_error"></span> </div><div class="feild"> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" /> <span id="val_email" class="val_error"></span> </div>  <div class="feild"><span id="val_selectAnIV" class="val_error"></span><div class="dd-wrapper-select"><select id="selectAnIV" name="selectAnIV" value="select"><option value="-1">SELECT AN TREATMENT</option><option>Option-1</option><option>Option-2</option><option>Option-3</option><option>Option-4</option></select></div></div><p> <a href="#" id="remScnt">sample</a></p></div>').appendTo(FileInputsHolder);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});
$("#remScnt").click(function () {
    alert('wprlog');
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('div').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="feild no-bor alignleft"> <span class="add-more"><a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox">+ Add a Patient</a></span> </div>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple identical IDs in the same document. You are duplicating the `remScnt` ID, as well as all the IDs inserted per patient field.

Comment: For future reference, try building and testing a jsfiddle for your questions. It makes everything quicker and easier for us who are trying to answer. http://jsfiddle.net/VFLZS/5/

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VFLZS/16/)**

Had to rewrite your code a bit:

```
var FileInputsHolder = $('#AddFileInputBox'); //Element where additional file inputs are appended
var MaxFileInputs = 3; //Maximum number of file input boxs
// adding and removing file input box
var i = $("#AddFileInputBox div").size() + 1;

$("#AddMoreFileBox").click(function () {
    console.log(i);
    if (i < MaxFileInputs) {
        $('<div class="patient-container"><h1>Patient-' + i + '</h1><div class="left-change" style="width:450px;"><div class="feild"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="FULL NAME" /><span id="val_name" class="val_error"></span> </div><div class="feild"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="PHONE" /><span id="val_phone" class="val_error"></span> </div><div class="feild"> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" /> <span id="val_email" class="val_error"></span> </div>  <div class="feild"><span id="val_selectAnIV" class="val_error"></span><div class="dd-wrapper-select"><select id="selectAnIV" name="selectAnIV" value="select"><option value="-1">SELECT AN TREATMENT</option><option>Option-1</option><option>Option-2</option><option>Option-3</option><option>Option-4</option></select></div></div><p> <a href="#" class="remScnt">sample</a></p></div></div>').appendTo(FileInputsHolder);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});
$(document).on("click", ".remScnt", function (e) {
    alert('wprlog');
    if (i > 1) {
        $(this).closest('.patient-container').remove();
        i--;
    }
    console.log(i);
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="feild no-bor alignleft"> <span class="add-more"><a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox">+ Add a Patient</a></span> 
</div>
<div id="AddFileInputBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a lot of tags `<a>` with the same id(remScnt). 
You can use jquery On to attach the remove handler dynamically

Check the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ and try to make something like

```
$("#someConteiner").on('click','.button-to-delete',function () {
  //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting with class of the element.

$("#remScnt").click(function () {

```
    $('.feild').remove();

}
```